# Having issues with Hikari and Postgres

Tags: jhipster

I keep getting these errors even though there are very few connections open.  I changed over to DBCP and no issues.

```
    [ERROR] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariPool - Maximum connection creation retries exceeded: FATAL: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.readStartupMessages(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:572) ~[postgresql-9.3-1100-jdbc41.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:177) ~[postgresql-9.3-1100-jdbc41.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:64) ~[postgresql-9.3-1100-jdbc41.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:136) ~[postgresql-9.3-1100-jdbc41.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:29) ~[postgresql-9.3-1100-jdbc41.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:21) ~[postgresql-9.3-1100-jdbc41.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:31) ~[postgresql-9.3-1100-jdbc41.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24) ~[postgresql-9.3-1100-jdbc41.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:410) ~[postgresql-9.3-1100-jdbc41.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:280) ~[postgresql-9.3-1100-jdbc41.jar:na]
```

Comment: Sounds as if you are not closing the connections properly.

Comment: I only have 13 connections open and those are from DBVisualizer.  The tomcat datasource is also causing this exception.

Comment: I'm able to open 3 connections and then on the forth it dies.  martinphee=# SELECT count(*) FROM pg_stat_activity;
 count 
-------
    17
(1 row)

Comment: #port = 5432                            # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 200

Comment: So you have the issue with Hikari and Tomcat JDBC, but not DBCP? Have you checked the state of Hikari? It's available throught JMX. The configuration might be wrong, I'm the one who wrote JHipster and I'm not a PostGresql expert (I'm using MySQL in fact), so feedback is really welcome

Comment: Figured it out.  Well kind of.  The user I created could only create 4 connections.  When I changed it to myself it worked find.

Comment: So it looks like I was actually hitting a postgres per user connection limit and not a server connection limit.  My bad.

Comment: OK, can you post it as an answer? I'm sure you're not the only one who could have this issue

Answer (score 2):

Does the new user have replication privileges?  It sounds like it does, which means from PostgreSQL's perspective that user *could* initiate replication.  The number of replication-capable connections are limited (though configurable).  I would check the new user you created and remove replication privileges from that user.  It should then be allowed to initiate up to the maximum number of configured connections.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Postgres.app for osx.  I created a user for a new application instead of the default user which is myself.  That user was only able to create three connections before getting the exception above.

```
PSQLException: FATAL: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections
```

It seems that Postgres.app sets the max connections to 20 and I'm unable to change that.  I tried, but I can't connect to postgres after changing it.  When I connect as the main user (my local user account) it doesn't seem to be affected, but the new user I created can't open enough connections.